# What is the Character Limit for Message text in Firebase console based notification?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications

i'm using Firebase console to send a notification to my phone, the notification is successfully delivered to my phone, but i want to know, What is the Character Limit for Message text in Firebase console based notification?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firebase uses GCM for message transport. Based on the following references

1. GCM Size Limit = 2KB ([here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options))
2. From FIrebase documentation size limit = 4KB ([here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref))

Anyway if we are considering a 2KB payload size. it will come around 2000 characters.

remember to keep the message size low as much as possible.

**UPDATE**

> The console will allow maximum of **1000 characters**

Comment: Note that messages sent from the console are notification messages and the message text could be used as the body of a notification displayed on the device. If your message is too long then it will be truncated.

Comment: Also note that eh UI will not allow a message text  of more than 1024 characters

Answer (score 6):

### As of today (1st Apr 2020)

Firebase console only allowing **1000** characters in the notification body:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Official docks now mention 1024 for the console and 4KB for the API

> Notification messages contain a predefined set of user-visible keys. Data messages, by contrast, contain only your user-defined custom key-value pairs. Notification messages can contain an optional data payload. Maximum payload for both message types is 4000 bytes, except when sending messages from the Firebase console, which enforces a 1024 character limit.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications